# Problema exibindo imagem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imagem, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

Como eu exibo uma imagem gravada no banco de dados, acredito que ela não esteja gravada de fato, porque eu só consigo visualizar o nome/formato da imagem. Nesse caso, como faço para exibir essa imagem?

Procurei algumas formas de fazer utilizando *custom HTML helpers* e etc., mas acho que estou esquecendo alguma coisa.

Segue o meu código para upload da imagem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Adicionar(usuario usuario, HttpPostedFileBase foto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.usuario.Add(usuario);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var fotoperfil = Path.GetFileName(foto.FileName);
        var caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Foto"), fotoperfil);
        foto.SaveAs(caminho);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(usuario);               
}
```

Comment: Não está sendo mesmo. Em que parte o *Model* de Usuário recebe o caminho do arquivo?

Comment: Bom, confesso que não fiz nenhuma alteração na model. Até porque eu não vi ninguém falando sobre. Só fiz a alteração na view e no controller mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa salvar a alteração no *Model*, como abaixo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Adicionar(usuario usuario, HttpPostedFileBase foto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.usuario.Add(usuario);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var fotoperfil = Path.GetFileName(foto.FileName);
        var caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Foto"), fotoperfil);
        foto.SaveAs(caminho);

        usuario.ArquivoDaFoto = caminho;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(usuario);               
}
```

`ArquivoDaFoto` deve ser `String`.

Comment: Entendi. Mas isso é o suficiente para exibir a foto num formulario, por exemplo?

Comment: É sim. Você só tem que colocar o conteúdo de `ArquivoDaFoto` dentro de uma tag `<img>`.

Comment: Tão simples e eu quebrando cabeça aqui. Obrigado.